# SQL Conditional Counting

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I am working with a dataset that contains information about train delays. The dataset contains an arrival delay column and departing delay column. Each delay column is measured in minutes. I need to calculate the number of total delays for each day of the week to determine which day has the most train delays. If the delay is equal to or more than 1 minute, it needs to be counted as a delay. How can I complete this in SQL? I have tried the following code.

```
select dayofweek
count(case when arrivaldelay>=1 then 1 end)+
count(case when departuredelay>=1 then 1 end)
group by dayofweek;

dayofweek  arrivaldelay   departuredelay
 2             12              5
 4             7               10
 4             6               -3
 6             5                4

dayofweek    delays
  2            1
  4            1
  6            1
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) What is the issue with your query?  (3) Sample data and desired results usually help.

Comment: The database is extremely large and I would have a hard time tagging it. I have attached some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: Use **Edit Tags**: When we ask to "tag" for the database, we mean please **choose a tag on the question** that tells us which database you use (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, Postgres etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming dayofweek is a stored column and not a function, then you can use either `count` or `sum`

```
select
      dayofweek
     , count(case when arrivaldelay >= 1 then 1 end)
       + count(case when departuredelay >= 1 then 1 end)
       as delays
from mytable as t
group by dayofweek;

select
      dayofweek
     , sum(case when arrivaldelay >= 1 then 1 else 0 end)
       + sum(case when departuredelay >= 1 then 1 else 0 end)
       as delays
from mytable as t
group by dayofweek;
```

both give the following result from the sample data in the question

```
+-----------+--------+
| dayofweek | delays |
+-----------+--------+
|         2 |      2 |
|         4 |      3 |
|         6 |      2 |
+-----------+--------+
```

IF dayofweek is NOT a stored column then you can extract the day of week from a date or timestamp, BUT there are differences in how this is achieved in different databases

*demonstrated @db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=662b5fad119e221ac9b3776fdb3a1b55)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` like this:

```
select dayofweek
       ( sum(case when arrivaldelay >= 1 then 1 else 0 end)+
         sum(case when departuredelay >= 1 then 1 else 0 end)
       )
from t
group by dayofweek;
```

Comment: I received an error. Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: dayofweek. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7

Comment: @KarlYujeck . . . Your question suggests that is a column in the data.  You should read my comment above and update the question appropriately.